# Class Scope Error in C++ [CLOSED)

Tags: c++, scope

Scope Error in C++ Classes. I have the following two classes:

```
class Tire
{
public:
    Tire();
    void width(int);
};

class Car
{
public:
    Car();
    void size();    
};

Car::Car()
{
    Tire mytire;
}
void Car::size()
{
    mytire.width(5);    // generates error: "mytire was not declared in this scope"
}
```

**EDIT:**
Silly mistake. I apologize for the inconvenience. I just haven't had enough sleep.

Comment: I had to type this into two different IDE's before I figured out what the error was too.

Comment: @JamesRoot sorry for the inconvenience this caused you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mytire` is not a member, it's a local variable in the constructor.
Move its declaration into the class definition.

```
class Car
{
public:
    Car();
    ~Car();
    void size();
private:
    Tire mytire;
};

Car::Car()
{
}
```

Comment: Oh silly me. I apologize for this question. it's late where I live, and I need to get some sleep.